# TFS CI/CD DB deployment. Getting error: The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 701

Tags: sql, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database

I am working on CI CD of DB deployment in TFS. In Release mode it is getting stuck in Deploy Azure SQL DACPAC step and continuously giving message "The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 701.".
Also the sql package process consuming all the memory of TFS server and it is getting hanged.
[image]

Comment: What is the tier of that Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please scale up the tier of the database. You may be hitting the DTU limit. Examine the DTU graph on Azure portal.

Once the deployment has finished, scale down the database tier, if you want, to maintain the same monthly costs.

Comment: yes this was the issue. Initially the DTU size was 10 only. Then I increased the size to 200 DTUs and magic happen and the Db deployment succeeded. Thanks Alberto.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred as SQL Server fail to allocate sufficient memory to run the query. This can be caused by number of reasons like Operating system settings, memory limit on current workload or physical memory availability. May be its time for an upgrade, or change what your query is pulling back or splitting it into separate queries.